# How to improve this particular machine learning question?

Tags: discussion

After asking a question, I usually receive down or upvotes, or comments, maybe an answer. I have asked this question recently: [How to algoritmically improve metric for k-nearest neighbors classification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4197294/how-to-algoritmically-improve-metric-for-k-nearest-neighbors-classification) and it seems to have slid under the radar completely (ie no down/upvotes, no comments, nothing).

How could I improve this question to make it more appealing? Or am I using the wrong site for this kind of questions?

Comment: I think this is something that's supposed to be asked in one of the Chat Rooms, not on Meta. Sadly, I don't know which chat room, and they're not particularly well documented / advertised. Hopefully someone will come along and suggest which one, and hopefully they will do so politely. :--)

Comment: Honestly, I think this is probably a better fit for a different stackexchange - maybe try [DataScience.SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)?